# Exercise books on functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have known a lot of excellent textbooks on functional analysis:

- Functional Analysis (Walter Rudin)
- Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations (Haim Brezis)

+....

I could not find some good **exercise books** on functional analysis.

Please help me to find some good books on exercise of functional analysis.

Thank you for all helping and comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try *[Exercises in Functional Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9048163994)* by Constantin Costara and Dumitru Popa.

Comment: Dear Sir. How can we get this book?

Comment: Thank you for your introduction of this book.

Comment: I second the recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

The book M. Fabian, P. Habala, P. Hajek, V. Montesinos, V. Zizler: *Banach Space Theory. The Basis of Linear and Nonlinear Analysis* has plenty of exercises at the and of each chapter.

Google Books [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C),
[MR2766381 (2012h:46001)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2766381),
[Zbl 1229.46001](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:1229.46001).

Comment: Thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 1):

There is the classic by Halmos, a problem book in Hilbert spaces. It is a GTM book so should be easy to find. Stein's Real Analysis and Functional Analysis might be also a good choice, if you want a broader flavor in analysis topics.